# Ruby on Rails - Having issue when generating a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when I try to run the server after creating a home/index page i get the following error. I wonder if you can help me.

Error: Cannot find module './templates.js'
Require stack:

- C:\railsfriends\friends\node_modules\chalk\index.js

Comment: is it `node.js` error ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error from the `chalk` javascript library, which can't find its expected `template.js` file. Try removing `chalk` from your `package.json` or wherever it's being loaded, so you can get the basic app working and then add it later, and debug the module then.

A 'nuclear' option (which is pretty safe on a new project, especially if you haven't touched the Javascript components yet) is to delete your node_modules directory from the project and then to run `yarn install` from a terminal in the project directory - this will read the required JS packages and install them again for you.

Not hugely helpful about the specific issue, I know, but the error message you posted tells you what the problem is, and it doesn't seem to be Rails itself. You may have more luck adding a tag for js and chalk specifically, to attract readers with that specific knowledge.